# How function can inherit a class attributes and methods in Javascript

Tags: javascript, function, class, object, ecmascript-6

In javascript I have a class and a function and I want the function to inherit the class attributes and methods.

As far as I know, when a function inherits another function we can use `call()` or `apply()` but what if a function inherits a class?

```
 class User{

    constructor(email_,name_){
        this.name=name_;
        this.email=email_;
    }

    login(){
        console.log(this.email+" has login");
    }
}


function Admin  (...args){

    User.apply(this,args);

}

var user1=new User("akrem","akrem@gmx.us");
var user2=new User("Luis","Luism@gmx.us");
var user3=new User("Karim","Karim@gmx.us");
var user4=new User("Yassine","assine@gmx.us");


var admin1=new Admin("Alex","alex@gmx.us");

console.group(admin1); //this gives error
```

Comment: This seems silly — If you are using classes, why aren't you using `extends`?

Comment: Class constructors can only be invoked via `new`. Either make `Admin` a proper class and `extend User` or make `User` a normal constructor function.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/extends

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing this wrong - to make a subclass, use `extends` and `super`:

```js
class User {

  constructor(email_, name_) {
    this.name = name_;
    this.email = email_;
  }

  login() {
    console.log(this.email + " has login");
  }
}


class Admin extends User {
  constructor(name, email) {
    super(email, name);
  }
  login() {
    console.log(this.name + " is an admin and has logged in.");
  }
}

var user1 = new User("akrem", "akrem@gmx.us");
var user2 = new User("Luis", "Luism@gmx.us");
var user3 = new User("Karim", "Karim@gmx.us");
var user4 = new User("Yassine", "assine@gmx.us");


var admin1 = new Admin("Alex", "alex@gmx.us");

console.log(admin1);

admin1.login();
```

If you really want to use spreading and functions, make both `User` and `Admin` ES5 constructors, and attach methods via prototyping:

```js
function User(email_, name_) {
  this.name = name_;
  this.email = email_;
}

User.prototype.login = function() {
  console.log(this.email + " has login");
}

function Admin(...args) {
  User.apply(this, args);
}

Admin.prototype.login = function() {
  console.log(this.name + " is an admin and has logged in.");
}

var user1 = new User("akrem", "akrem@gmx.us");
var user2 = new User("Luis", "Luism@gmx.us");
var user3 = new User("Karim", "Karim@gmx.us");
var user4 = new User("Yassine", "assine@gmx.us");


var admin1 = new Admin("alex@gmx.us", "Alex");

console.log(admin1);

admin1.login();
```